# What to do if a number becomes bigger than 10 on scientific notation when performing arithmetics with it?

Tags: notation, exponentiation

For example, I was adding (9.99 x 10<sup>4</sup>)+ (9.99 x 10<sup>5</sup>).

I raised the first number's exponent from <sup>4</sup> to <sup>5</sup> by dividing it by 10 once more, thus getting 0.999 and the 10<sup>5</sup> exponent as a way to reverse it (that's how I see scientific notation, you either divide or multiply by ten successive times and then you have the reverse process as scientific notation, so if I get a positive exponent, it reverts a corresponding exponentiation which has a negative exponent, and the converse is also true).

The problem is that after that, when adding 9.99 with .999 I get 10.989 and my final number is 10.989 x 10<sup>5</sup>, which is not a valid number in scientific notation as far as I know.

PS: sorry for my explanation, it feels a bit confused even to me, but that's the best I could conceive as an explanation to the issue I have.

TL;DR (9.99 x 10<sup>4</sup>)+ (9.99 x 10<sup>5</sup>) = 10.989 x 10<sup>5</sup>, how the hell do I solve it?

Comment: $10\times 10^5 = 1\times 10^6$.

Comment: Note that $10.989 = 1.0989\times 10^1$ and so $10.989\times 10^5 = (1.0989\times 10^1)\times 10^5 = 1.0989\times (10^1\times 10^5)=\dots$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that scientific notation is just a way to write a number. Its not a special code outside of other math. It's just like we identify the number $20$ and the number $4\times 5$ since they are equal.

So in this case, we want to write $9.99\times 10^4+9.99\times 10^5$ in scientific notation. We can use the fact that
$$9.99\times 10^5=9.99\times 10\times 10^4=99.9\times 10^4$$
along with the fact that $ax+bx=(a+b)x$ to see
$$9.99\times 10^4+9.99\times 10^5=109.89\times 10^4.$$
Now $109.89=1.0989\times 10^2$, so we have
$$109.89\times 10^4=1.0989\times 10^2\times 10^4=1.0989\times 10^6.$$

Comment: Got it, thanks.